# Discrepancy between lme4 sample size and complete case dataset?

Tags: r, missing-data, lme4, multi-level

I'm currently estimating a hierarchical linear model (HLM) using lme4. My entire dataset has 367 observations. lme4 estimated my model using 341 observations - I assumed some were dropped due to missing data. However, when I sum the complete cases on the model's variables, I end up with 337 observations. This is making it difficult to test for assumptions when the model is a different length than the dataset.

**There is a discrepancy between complete cases and the observations 'used' by lme4.**

1. Why would lme4 use 4 non-complete cases?
2. How would I find out what exact observations (as ID #s) are being used by lme4?

As described, I tried to remove missing data from my main dataset assuming lme4 drops cases listwise. I've tried checking each variable for its missingness to see if lme4 was just testing a certain variable, but none match up with lme4's output estimate of 341.

If needed, I can provide the anonymized dataset - but hoping there's something easy I'm not aware of!

Comment: *"However, when I sum the complete cases on the model's variables, I end up with 337 observations."* At least post the code you used for your model and that you used for this check so we can see if it looks right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious reason would be that `lme4` (and internally `model.frame`) assesses completeness only on the basis of the variables that are actually used in the model. Do you have `NA` values in variables that are not included in the model formula?

(For what it's worth, this default also means that it's a good idea to filter the full data set for complete cases *first* if you are going to fit a series of models with different subsets of predictors and want the models to be comparable ...)

Example:

```r
library(lme4)
ss <- sleepstudy
ss$Days[c(1, 4, 10)] <- NA
ss$extra <- 1
ss$extra[c(4, 20, 25)] <- NA
```

```r
nrow(ss)  ## 180
sum(complete.cases(ss))  ## 175; drops obs with missing `extra`
m <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), ss, na.action = na.omit)
mf <- model.frame(m)
nrow(mf)  ## 177; ignores variables not in the model
```

Which rows were deleted?  Two ways to check:

```r
attr(mf, "na.action")
 1  4 10 
 1  4 10 
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

```r
setdiff(rownames(ss), rownames(mf))
[1] "1"  "4"  "10"
```

The equivalent to the internal code is

```r
nrow(model.frame(Reaction ~ Days + Subject, ss))  ## 177
```

(the formula gets processed so that the random effects grouping variables are also included in the formula for the purpose of excluding incomplete cases)

Comment: Thanks for this info. You're correct. I had multiple, slightly different models (the second model introduced a new variable) - therefore, the second model was introducing a source of missingness that the first model didn't have, and the sample sizes were slightly different. Appreciate the help from all!